# Draw a border around mkmapview,scrollview and webview 

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview, uiscrollview, mkmapview

I am developing an iPhone application in which I have a page in which I am using scrollview mkmapview and webview all at once in the control of a segmented control.

I am doing it confortablly .

My question is that I want to show border or frame outside this frames.

How can I do so ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here How you can do ::

```
self.posterView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
self.posterView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
```

one thing do not forget to include `<QuartzCore/Quartcore.h>` and include the framework as well

enjoy